# Evaluate square of first Chern class on K3 Surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry, riemann-surfaces

I want to let $X$ be a K3 surface, with $Y \subset X$ a smooth curve with genus $g$.  Since $Y$ is a hypersurface, we have a line bundle $\mathcal{O}(Y)$ on $X$.  I'm curious how to prove the following statement,

$\int_{X} c_{1}^{2}(\mathcal{O}(Y)) = 2g-2$

I feel like I most likely need to use some exact sequence, perhaps like,

$0 \to \mathcal{O}(-Y) \to \mathcal{O}_{X} \to \mathcal{O}_{Y} \to 0$,

but I'm not totally sure how.  Also, perhaps there are other ways to get at this formula, but I'm hoping for a rather direct argument specifically pertaining to this integral.  Much thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you mean $Y=C$?

Comment: ugh, yes thank you!  Edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are basically correct. What you're looking for is the *adjunction formula*, which states that (for a smooth hypersufrace $Y \subset X$
$$
K_Y = K_X|_Y \otimes N_{Y/X}
$$
where $N_{Y/X}$ is the normal bundle of $Y$ in $X$; in the case of a line bundle, we have that $N_{Y/X} \cong \mathscr{O}_X(Y)|_Y$. Since the canonical bundle of a K3 surface is trivial, we have that $K_Y = \mathscr{O}_X(Y)|_Y$

In particular, since
$$
\int_X c_1\mathscr{O}_X(Y)^2 = \deg \mathscr{O}_X(Y)|_Y
$$
by Poincaré duality, the claim follows.

Comment: Is it more or less by definition that $\int c_{1}^{2}( \mathcal{O}(Y) = \rm{deg} K_{Y}$?  I'm not really seeing where Poincare duality comes in.

Comment: Since the homology class of a curve $C$ is Poincaré dual to $c_1(\mathscr{O}_X(D))$, Poincaré duality can be essentially stated that
$$\int_X \omega \cup c_1(\mathscr{O}_X(D)) = \int_C i_C^*\omega$$ which is what that last formula says.

Comment: Ah I see, so in your formula above, I should simply take $\omega = c_{1}(\mathcal{O}_{X}(D))$, in which case the integral over the curve $C$ on the right hand side just reduces to the degree of the curve which is $2g-2$?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly correct.

Answer (score 2):

We have $c_1(\mathcal O(D))=D$ for any divisor $D$, as you can find in the short appendix on chern classes in Hartshorne.

So you are basically searching for the self-intersection number $\int_X C.C$ of a divisor on a surface. This is the adjunction formula (Hartshorne, Proposition V.1.5), which states $2g-2=\int_X C.(C+K)$. In your case, $K=0$, so we are done.